# Estou com dificuldade no alinhamento

Tags: html, html5

Sou iniciante e estou tentando a todo custo deixar a descrição da seguinte maneira;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando colo o html no adm da plataforma, a descrição fica desalinhada;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```html
<h3 class="why-trocafone__title" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
<br /></h3>
<h3 class="why-trocafone__title" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
Como é o Produto?</h3>
<h3 class="why-trocafone__title" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
<div class="why-trocafone__subtitle" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: black; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.377rem; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span style="color: #666666;">É um produto que ficou exposto em uma vitrine fechada na loja do Fabricante, ou da operadora, podendo conter pequenos riscos, amassados, ou não estar em sua embalagem original.</span></div>
<div class="why-trocafone_reasons" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #404040; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 15px; width: 938px;">
<div class="reason" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
<img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAeK7BirU2-ywHBqHthSJYv--Ktxq1VNi8-01NUpAQB6I7-k_pEDpUV95q_DCeIIG61Y7K8UM4sh4xV0UySfEl7DqjGh68swOdclc9FTDAeOHhR3jpAHL3SWoRkCvnDMwJpDuPKU7Aeu4bBmbWuZpOt0NolJw3rxDzC_ulryUzul9h4HDt5TagthUOhfE5BQn4RMOKvGO3Pjq5DxM538cdvrSkRBMOyyIiJNuCQEmMl68PZ05T72euvdLBnxmO0SPPFFg8h6sI2EskOMZ0pV5POPMYs9FBn8ztBJA_jSCJFdNlajGcKbZqxngFBaDYiQO_Oaam0MDR7AT7a_mId1CvtS/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAeK7BirU2-ywHBqHthSJYv--Ktxq1VNi8-01NUpAQB6I7-k_pEDpUV95q_DCeIIG61Y7K8UM4sh4xV0UySfEl7DqjGh68swOdclc9FTDAeOHhR3jpAHL3SWoRkCvnDMwJpDuPKU7Aeu4bBmbWuZpOt0NolJw3rxDzC_ulryUzul9h4HDt5TagthUOhfE5BQn4RMOKvGO3Pjq5DxM538cdvrSkRBMOyyIiJNuCQEmMl68PZ05T72euvdLBnxmO0SPPFFg8h6sI2EskOMZ0pV5POPMYs9FBn8ztBJA_jSCJFdNlajGcKbZqxngFBaDYiQO_Oaam0MDR7AT7a_mId1CvtS/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" />&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Produto funcional, original e com Nf-e</span></div>
&nbsp;<div class="reason" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
<img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAdtVVTsu_E0onuH11nGdKRPue9LdDjNgSZ7hKQ_rF6AWiTS_4xTiMDQNfe6xKLku4v9KqnPeC9LUBOdgXDstpKx7kDyQo1DKEoAXZISDORZA62XlzqnDa601PKkl4VaOV51mrCAmLOJ3IrQGQJAXqVP8fIHWDu24gvxcj57ybp-Ub9OsIWKjCjTkghtXYma3t1FZU-ePOGXgb9eBgXvpnUjNwoiwAXaS4x1UmZZpOM-RhIL9e4oAMmhHqrApEXwz9nzkYZOEPd4RWAS8GWWz2sGgbAdEsbUWXzDLdlDEsRATNvw7WVmyE5le5CMitb0y-3wwwRYtq28Sb-Xj2vzNiKs/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAdtVVTsu_E0onuH11nGdKRPue9LdDjNgSZ7hKQ_rF6AWiTS_4xTiMDQNfe6xKLku4v9KqnPeC9LUBOdgXDstpKx7kDyQo1DKEoAXZISDORZA62XlzqnDa601PKkl4VaOV51mrCAmLOJ3IrQGQJAXqVP8fIHWDu24gvxcj57ybp-Ub9OsIWKjCjTkghtXYma3t1FZU-ePOGXgb9eBgXvpnUjNwoiwAXaS4x1UmZZpOM-RhIL9e4oAMmhHqrApEXwz9nzkYZOEPd4RWAS8GWWz2sGgbAdEsbUWXzDLdlDEsRATNvw7WVmyE5le5CMitb0y-3wwwRYtq28Sb-Xj2vzNiKs/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" /><span style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Acompanha todos os acessórios originais do modelo</span></div>
&nbsp;<div class="reason" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
<img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAfF0czY1iixR-hF5xYqcp_O0lekQj-O6YYIuBfsSs4150YDBz6ReXsftgrvAiYTmJwm4fvLI_yEM7MXVeXCdZ2eXkcp2KLGZd9PJwW2_gMXPvql5dUNuavier-8JwusdP-N6DMRA_oXIuUsV7WKychjiIAE3Ij8q6ukTohftnSha00sERqQojm6fondbn6segpCzW-Qa1iuv86WtArTCR-u3TYVussHNgmOhw7iUuhUd0WwOKvD7c57-FpFTThsatYHbW2pjXyUfzuaTfMU6MAD3V2xBRY3MoVTgKCVfoWyilz8VoTjpGOaYHcCdm9_F_lVkzGWo33duY5s5BESNOFz/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAfF0czY1iixR-hF5xYqcp_O0lekQj-O6YYIuBfsSs4150YDBz6ReXsftgrvAiYTmJwm4fvLI_yEM7MXVeXCdZ2eXkcp2KLGZd9PJwW2_gMXPvql5dUNuavier-8JwusdP-N6DMRA_oXIuUsV7WKychjiIAE3Ij8q6ukTohftnSha00sERqQojm6fondbn6segpCzW-Qa1iuv86WtArTCR-u3TYVussHNgmOhw7iUuhUd0WwOKvD7c57-FpFTThsatYHbW2pjXyUfzuaTfMU6MAD3V2xBRY3MoVTgKCVfoWyilz8VoTjpGOaYHcCdm9_F_lVkzGWo33duY5s5BESNOFz/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" />&nbsp; &nbsp;<span style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Garantia de 12 meses com o Fabricante</span></div>
<div class="reason" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
<br /></div>
&nbsp;</div>
<div>
<br style="font-size: 19.36px;" /></div>
</h3>
<div>
<div class="reason" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
<span style="font-size: xx-small;">
</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sem o HTML e um [mcve] será impossível te ajudar. Por favor, busque [edit] e complementar sua pergunta.

Comment: Insira seus códigos HTML e CSS para ficar mais fácil para a gente te ajudar.

Comment: Eu havia esquecido, já adicionei o código.

Comment: Essas classes não possuem CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta na `div` que tem a classe `.why-trocafone_reasons` vc adicionar `margin: 15px auto 0;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código

```html
 <h3 class="why-trocafone__title"
  style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
  <br /></h3>
 <h3 class="why-trocafone__title"
  style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
  Como é o Produto?</h3>
 <h3 class="why-trocafone__title"
  style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #4d649b; font-family: Montserrat, &quot;open sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.21rem; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
  <div class="why-trocafone__subtitle"
   style="box-sizing: border-box; color: black; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.377rem; margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <span style="color: #666666;">É um produto que ficou exposto em uma vitrine fechada na loja do Fabricante,
    ou da operadora, podendo conter pequenos riscos, amassados, ou não estar em sua embalagem
    original.</span></div>
  <div class="why-trocafone_reasons"
   style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #404040; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; margin: 15px auto 0; width: 938px;">
   <div class="reason"
    style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
    <img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAeK7BirU2-ywHBqHthSJYv--Ktxq1VNi8-01NUpAQB6I7-k_pEDpUV95q_DCeIIG61Y7K8UM4sh4xV0UySfEl7DqjGh68swOdclc9FTDAeOHhR3jpAHL3SWoRkCvnDMwJpDuPKU7Aeu4bBmbWuZpOt0NolJw3rxDzC_ulryUzul9h4HDt5TagthUOhfE5BQn4RMOKvGO3Pjq5DxM538cdvrSkRBMOyyIiJNuCQEmMl68PZ05T72euvdLBnxmO0SPPFFg8h6sI2EskOMZ0pV5POPMYs9FBn8ztBJA_jSCJFdNlajGcKbZqxngFBaDYiQO_Oaam0MDR7AT7a_mId1CvtS/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5"
     temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAeK7BirU2-ywHBqHthSJYv--Ktxq1VNi8-01NUpAQB6I7-k_pEDpUV95q_DCeIIG61Y7K8UM4sh4xV0UySfEl7DqjGh68swOdclc9FTDAeOHhR3jpAHL3SWoRkCvnDMwJpDuPKU7Aeu4bBmbWuZpOt0NolJw3rxDzC_ulryUzul9h4HDt5TagthUOhfE5BQn4RMOKvGO3Pjq5DxM538cdvrSkRBMOyyIiJNuCQEmMl68PZ05T72euvdLBnxmO0SPPFFg8h6sI2EskOMZ0pV5POPMYs9FBn8ztBJA_jSCJFdNlajGcKbZqxngFBaDYiQO_Oaam0MDR7AT7a_mId1CvtS/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" />&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Produto funcional,
     original e com Nf-e</span></div>
   &nbsp;<div class="reason"
    style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
    <img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAdtVVTsu_E0onuH11nGdKRPue9LdDjNgSZ7hKQ_rF6AWiTS_4xTiMDQNfe6xKLku4v9KqnPeC9LUBOdgXDstpKx7kDyQo1DKEoAXZISDORZA62XlzqnDa601PKkl4VaOV51mrCAmLOJ3IrQGQJAXqVP8fIHWDu24gvxcj57ybp-Ub9OsIWKjCjTkghtXYma3t1FZU-ePOGXgb9eBgXvpnUjNwoiwAXaS4x1UmZZpOM-RhIL9e4oAMmhHqrApEXwz9nzkYZOEPd4RWAS8GWWz2sGgbAdEsbUWXzDLdlDEsRATNvw7WVmyE5le5CMitb0y-3wwwRYtq28Sb-Xj2vzNiKs/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5"
     temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAdtVVTsu_E0onuH11nGdKRPue9LdDjNgSZ7hKQ_rF6AWiTS_4xTiMDQNfe6xKLku4v9KqnPeC9LUBOdgXDstpKx7kDyQo1DKEoAXZISDORZA62XlzqnDa601PKkl4VaOV51mrCAmLOJ3IrQGQJAXqVP8fIHWDu24gvxcj57ybp-Ub9OsIWKjCjTkghtXYma3t1FZU-ePOGXgb9eBgXvpnUjNwoiwAXaS4x1UmZZpOM-RhIL9e4oAMmhHqrApEXwz9nzkYZOEPd4RWAS8GWWz2sGgbAdEsbUWXzDLdlDEsRATNvw7WVmyE5le5CMitb0y-3wwwRYtq28Sb-Xj2vzNiKs/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" /><span
     style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Acompanha todos os acessórios
     originais do modelo</span></div>
   &nbsp;<div class="reason"
    style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
    <img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAfF0czY1iixR-hF5xYqcp_O0lekQj-O6YYIuBfsSs4150YDBz6ReXsftgrvAiYTmJwm4fvLI_yEM7MXVeXCdZ2eXkcp2KLGZd9PJwW2_gMXPvql5dUNuavier-8JwusdP-N6DMRA_oXIuUsV7WKychjiIAE3Ij8q6ukTohftnSha00sERqQojm6fondbn6segpCzW-Qa1iuv86WtArTCR-u3TYVussHNgmOhw7iUuhUd0WwOKvD7c57-FpFTThsatYHbW2pjXyUfzuaTfMU6MAD3V2xBRY3MoVTgKCVfoWyilz8VoTjpGOaYHcCdm9_F_lVkzGWo33duY5s5BESNOFz/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5"
     temp_src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AAfF0czY1iixR-hF5xYqcp_O0lekQj-O6YYIuBfsSs4150YDBz6ReXsftgrvAiYTmJwm4fvLI_yEM7MXVeXCdZ2eXkcp2KLGZd9PJwW2_gMXPvql5dUNuavier-8JwusdP-N6DMRA_oXIuUsV7WKychjiIAE3Ij8q6ukTohftnSha00sERqQojm6fondbn6segpCzW-Qa1iuv86WtArTCR-u3TYVussHNgmOhw7iUuhUd0WwOKvD7c57-FpFTThsatYHbW2pjXyUfzuaTfMU6MAD3V2xBRY3MoVTgKCVfoWyilz8VoTjpGOaYHcCdm9_F_lVkzGWo33duY5s5BESNOFz/p.png?fv_content=true&amp;size_mode=5" />&nbsp;
    &nbsp;<span style="color: #4d649b; font-size: 0.933rem; font-weight: 600;">Garantia de 12 meses com o
     Fabricante</span></div>
   <div class="reason"
    style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
    <br /></div>
   &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div>
   <br style="font-size: 19.36px;" /></div>
 </h3>
 <div>
  <div class="reason"
   style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; width: calc(20% - 4px);">
   <span style="font-size: xx-small;">
   </span></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: No ADM do site and Blog ficou da mesma maneira, mas quando eu executo o seu código aqui, fica da maneira que eu quero. D:

Comment: @HenriqueMorelli tente colocar no CSS `.why-trocafone_reasons { margin: 15px auto 0 !important;}` acho que com o !important deve pegar a propriedade

Answer (score 0):

Tem muita coisa para ser otimizada nesse seu código, mas aqui vai a solução para o que vc está buscando:

Encontre esse trecho de código:

```
<div class="why-trocafone_reasons" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #404040; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 15px; width: 938px;">
```

E substitua por esse:

```
 <div class="why-trocafone_reasons" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #404040; font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; margin: 15px auto 0; width: 938px; text-align: center;">
```

Comment: Substitui, mas ficou mais desalinhado ainda.

Comment: Será se não é problema de Cache?

Comment: Não, ele ainda continua do mesmo jeito! D:

Comment: Não sei se vc percebeu, eu também no percebi no começo, você possui um <div class="reason"></div> vazio (o ultimo), ou seja, sem nenhum dado, o que pode causar a impressão de desalinhamento, mas na verdade não está desalinhado, apenas tem uma div ocupando espaço sem nenhum conteúdo dentro dela. Confira aí no seu código e me informe...

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, códigos css inline não são boas práticas, além de atrapalharem muito no desenvolvimento e manutenção.

Experimente usar nas imgs: `display: block; margin: 0 auto;`